# Using btrfs RAID0 with different drive sizes results in low space available

Tags: disk-usage, btrfs

I have similar problem like unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/

```
btrfs filesystem show
Label: none  uuid: 3fdeaf6d-ca88-4cc8-8405-f882f02693f7
    Total devices 3 FS bytes used 1.53MB
    devid    3 size 931.51GB used 2.00GB path /dev/sdd
    devid    2 size 931.51GB used 2.00GB path /dev/sdb
    devid    1 size 3.64TB used 2.02GB path /dev/sda

Btrfs v0.20-rc1

df -h | grep mnt
/dev/sdb        5.5T  1.6M  2.8T   1% /mnt/btrfs

btrfs fi df /mnt/btrfs/
Data, RAID0: total=3.00GB, used=1.50MB
Data: total=8.00MB, used=0.00
System, RAID0: total=15.94MB, used=4.00KB
System: total=4.00MB, used=0.00
Metadata, RAID0: total=3.00GB, used=24.00KB
Metadata: total=8.00MB, used=0.00
```

I don't know why I have available only 2,8T?

Comment: see the faq: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#How_much_free_space_do_I_have.3F

Comment: * single and RAID-0 have no correction

Answer (score 2):

In Raid0 BTRFS will only use the size of the smallest drive on every other drive... in your case `0.93TB * 3 HD = 2.8TB HD`